# Selenium find_element(By.XPATH) not working inside python try loop

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath

`find_element(By.XPATH)` works everywhere in my code except where I need it to work. The code worked fine until I changed something somewhere and I can't figure out what it is. I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
number_of_usernames_found_on_page = 0
while number_of_usernames_found_on_page < 20:
    try:
        username_iteration = number_of_usernames_found_on_page + 1
        found_username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="semisocial"]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[' + (str(username_iteration)) + ']/div/div/div[1]/a/div/div/span[2]').text
        print("%s: %s" % (str(username_iteration)), (str(found_username)))
        number_of_usernames_found_on_page += 1
    except:           
        print("\nCan't find username number %s on page." % (number_of_usernames_found_on_page + 1))
        number_of_usernames_found_on_page = 0
        break
```

The `found_username` xpath line is what is causing the problem. I've tried copyng it and pasting it outside the try loop and it works fine. It's able to find the element text and save it to the variable. But as soon as I put it in the try loop it fails. What's the problem with it?

**EDIT:** I found the problem. After the `xpath` line, I was missing an extra parenthesis on the print function. Totally unrelated to what I thought it was. Thanks @JeffC for the help.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Did you try printing the built XPath and then checking that on the page in the browser dev tools? Maybe the XPath isn't being built correctly or it's just not correct for the current state of the page, etc.

Comment: @JeffC I tried that. Everywhere else I put that code it prints the correct xpath. But as soon as I put it in the loop it doesn't work.

Comment: @Prophet It's a private page. You can't access it without an account given by the admin of the site.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Can you explain? I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Just to be clear... you printed the XPath inside the loop? You also tried a breakpoint inside the loop and tried the printed XPath on the page using the dev tools at that point?

Comment: @JeffC When I print it inside the loop, it doesn't show anything. But when it's outside the loop it prints it just fine. I was able to find the XPath on the page manually with dev tools. Something about this loop is throwing it off but I don't know what.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the help. I fixed the problem. It was totally unrelated. Check the edit for the solution.